# sudo: /private/etc/sudoers.d is owned by uid 501 should be 0 - unable to run sudo commands on terminal - big sur

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, malware, sudo

My brew command was getting stuck without any output. So I tried reinstalling brew. When I try to re-install using:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

It says:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is owned by uid 501, should be 0
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
```

I then tried to run following (as answered on the other related questions) with sudo commands and it gave me the same error:

```
chown root:wheel /etc/sudoers; chmod 440 /etc/sudoers; chmod -N /etc/sudoers
```

I checked on all the other questions related to this but couldn't find anything. So basically, I cant run anything with sudo. Many of my apps are crashing. Can someone help?

Comment: Please be specific about the things you've tried and how they failed. "It doesn't work" doesn't give us much insights, could be a wrong command, a typo, executing something in the wrong directory etrc.

Comment: added everything, can you pls help if you can

Comment: The best way is booting in Recovery mode (cmd+r at boot) then select in the top menu Utility/Terminal and try the command  ````chown root:wheel /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/etc/sudoers````  Two things : if your system volume name is different adapt the command, and if you have activate Filevault, you need to unlock the system volume from disk utility  (always from recovery mode) before use the terminal command.